# How to I boot when I get grub error?

Tags: grub2

[image: Gparted]With the computer switched off, I disconnected my SSD drive which has Ubuntu installed. I connected another ssd and installed windows on it.  I then disconnected it and re-connected my ssd drive that has Ubuntu on it.  But when I tried to boot, I got a black screen with

No such partition
Entering rescure mode
Grub rescue

Gparted show the attached partitions, I think the /dev/sbd1 is to blame as it is a NTFS partition.  Would deleteing this fix the probelem?

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: When doing such switches you need to adjust the UEFI ("BIOS") boot settings each time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)